# Asymptotic for zeroes of $L(s,\chi)$ in a disk $|s|<R$

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

In 'Remarks on Weil's quadratic functional..' p.191 Bombieri claims any given $L$-function $L(s,\chi)$ has at least
$$\big(\frac{1}{\pi}+o(1)\big)R\log R$$
zeroes in a disk $|s|<R$. Is there a reference and/or a proof of this statement that I can cite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this is what he's claiming exactly, since if you position your disk in the strip $\Re s > 1$ then the count is zero. I realize now that most likely the disk is expanding (that is $R$ goes to infinity) in that case this follows just from the usual count of zeros which is known to be $(1/2\pi) T \log T + (\text{easy small stuff}) + O(\log T)$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$. The conductor of the L-function also has to be fixed.

Comment: Whoops. I realize that the claim was in fact for $\zeta(s)$ instead of $L(s,\chi)$. What I'm looking for is the analogous estimate for $L(s,\chi)$. I think you're right that it probably follows from the $N(T)$ asymptotic.

Comment: Yes, for fixed $q$ the asymptotic for $N(T,\chi)$ is exactly this. More precisely, it's $\frac1\pi R\log \frac{qR}{2\pi e} + O_q(\log R)$.

Comment: @GregMartin : the asymptotic number of zeros for different $L(s,\chi)$ depend only on $q$ ? (where $\chi$ is a character modulo $q$) what about the non-primitive characters, or the principal characters $L(s,\chi_0 \pmod q)$  ?

Comment: Good clarification: the formula as I quoted it applies to primitive characters (so for nonprimitive characters, one needs to replace $q$ by the actual conductor). Other than that, it's uniform over $\chi$.